# javaCameraView not working on oneplus3t

Tags: opencv, android, oneplusthree

Its my first OpenCV project and I have coded to covert an image to grayscale and canny image. The app is working perfectly on Samsung phone but not working on One Plus 3T.

Comment: There could be "Permission" issues. As android versions above Marshmallow are pretty strict in case of permissions your app required and often you have to grant permissions for camera or storage manually by going into your phone's settings.

Comment: obviously i have grant the permissions for the app from settings app info